# phpmyadmin not working on ubuntu

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Few days before my localhost stopped working saying error 303.I have solved the error now localhost is working but phpmyadmin stopped working. I have tried changing the password in opt/lampp/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php

Before :

```
/* Authentication type */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
/* Server parameters */
//$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
//$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;

After:
/* Authentication type */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'test'; <----changed this

/* Server parameters */
//$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
//$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false; <----changed this
```

I've Restarted the Apache, but still it does not work.
Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: so what the error?

Comment: Error "Cannot connect: invalid settings.
Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.
phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server rejected the connection. You should check the host, username and password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server."

Comment: Is this your entire config.inc.php? The error message indicates a problem with configuration directives for 'controluser' and 'controlpass' which I don't see included in what you've posted. Normally, I'd suggest commenting out those two directives in order to bypass the error.

Comment: It worked @IsaacBennetch. Thank you